# How to differentiate the multiple panels with login and session?

Tags: codeigniter, session, authentication, admin

It create the session but does not go to index2 and index3 always redirect with else and go to index method but i want to go index2 and index3 to handle other panels also.

Session is created successfully for all just comming else condition all the time.

My form data and array is also showing when i using the print_r for my code to view if the data is comming or not.

Problem is it is showing no any error just redirect with file of index method.

My Controller

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Main_Model');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('session');

    $method = $this->router->fetch_method();
    $methods = array('index','index2','index3');
    if(in_array($method,$methods))
    {
        if(!$this->session->has_userdata('signup_email'))
        {
            redirect(base_url('Main/login'));
        }
    }       
}

public function index()
{
    if($this->session->has_userdata('signup_email'))
    {
        $this->load->view('BKO/index');
    }
}

public function index2()
{
    if($this->session->has_userdata('signup_email'))
    {
        $this->load->view('Admin/index');
    }
}

public function index3()
{
    if($this->session->has_userdata('signup_email'))
    {
        $this->load->view('Owner/index');
    }
}

public function login()
{   
    //$data['select'] = $this->Main_Model->get_select();
    $this->load->view('login');
}

public function login_process()
{
    //$roll = $this->input->post('select');
    echo $email = $this->input->post('email');
    echo $pass = $this->input->post('upass');

$query = $this->Main_Model->login_process($email,$pass);

    if($query == TRUE)
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('signup_email');
        $session = array(
                'signup_email' => $email 
                );
        $this->session->set_userdata($session);
        redirect(base_url('Main/check_login'));
    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid Email or Password');
        redirect(base_url('Main/login'));

    }
}

public function check_login()
{
    if($this->session->userdata() == 'admin@gmail.com')
    {
        echo "Welcome - <h2>".$this->session->userdata('username')."</h2>";
        redirect(base_url('Main/index2'));  
    }

    elseif($this->session->userdata() == 'owner@gmail.com')
    {
        echo "Welcome - <h2>".$this->session->userdata('username')."</h2>";
        redirect(base_url('Main/index3'));  
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Welcome - <h2>".$this->session->userdata('username')."</h2>";
        redirect(base_url('Main/index'));   
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect(base_url());
}
```

My Model

```
    public function login_process($email,$pass)
    {
        //$this->db->select('*');
        //$this->db->where('roll_id',$roll);
        $this->db->where('signup_email',$email);
        $this->db->where('signup_password',$pass);

        $query = $this->db->get('signup');

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('signup_email');
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the parameter here

`if($this->session->userdata() == 'admin@gmail.com')`

instead it should be

```
if($this->session->userdata('signup_email') == 'admin@gmail.com')
```

Comment: Thanks to remove my headache

Comment: @SunnySagar I will not ask to accept my answer but i have seen you asked many question none of them as accepted answer from you,it discourages community .

Comment: i don't know about this earlier now i will understand this thnks for ur suggestion.